# Замена даты коммитов в GIT

Tags: git, git-rebase

Хочу добавить существующий репозиторий на GitHub. Так как он отображает дату коммита из поля CommitDate, то для всех коммитов хочу выставить CommitDate равное AuthorDate. Для команды `git rebase` нашёл опцию `--committer-date-is-author-date`. Выполнил для всех коммитов, начиная от самых древних. Но у **начального коммита** дата не изменилась. Собственно говоря, почему?

```
user@PC ~/myrepo
$ git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date e727c96
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Применение: Return correct error code in error callback
Применение: Move files to root folder

user@PC ~/myrepo
$ git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date 9e61101
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Применение: Move files to root folder

user@PC ~/myrepo
$ git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date a0c1b7a
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded master to a0c1b7a.

user@PC ~/myrepo
$ git log --pretty=fuller
commit a0c1b7a9d5c331a088555567d20631d94c107523 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author:     XXXX <xxxx@xxxx>
AuthorDate: Sun Jan 10 13:25:15 2021 +0300
Commit:     XXXX <xxxx@xxxx>
CommitDate: Sun Jan 10 13:25:15 2021 +0300

    Move files to root folder

commit 9e611015ee95fbacf0ee267e0770c1eeda28b8aa
Author:     XXXX <xxxx@xxxx>
AuthorDate: Sun Jun 14 21:34:58 2020 +0300
Commit:     XXXX <xxxx@xxxx>
CommitDate: Sun Jun 14 21:34:58 2020 +0300

    Return correct error code in error callback

commit e727c9609b0787d8b93f0570cd36389a36cc79f0
Author:     XXXX <xxxx@xxxx>
AuthorDate: Tue Mar 31 19:32:50 2020 +0300
Commit:     XXXX <xxxx@xxxx>
CommitDate: Sun Jan 10 13:16:23 2021 +0300

    Initial commit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но у начального коммита дата не изменилась. Собственно говоря, почему?

при выполнении

```
$ git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date хэш
```

изменяется коммит, являющийся потомком коммита с указанным хэшем. т.е., для изменения некогего коммита надо указать хэш его **предка**.

а у самого первого коммита в истории предка нет. соответственно, подобной командой изменить самый первый коммит невозможно.

---

> для всех коммитов хочу выставить CommitDate равное AuthorDate

этого можно добиться, например, командой `filter-branch` с опцией `--commit-filter`. вот так будут изменены даты «committer date» у всех коммитов, достижимых из того, на который указывает спецуказатель `HEAD`:

```
$ git filter-branch --commit-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="${GIT_AUTHOR_DATE}" git commit-tree "$@"'
```

---

иллюстрация. сначала:

```
$ git log --pretty=fuller
commit aef63a9e414abf06c92bae83c14269b1fa2b59a2 (HEAD -> master)
Author:     user <user@host>
AuthorDate: Wed Jan 1 01:01:02 2020 +0300
Commit:     user <user@host>
CommitDate: Sun Feb 2 02:02:02 2020 +0300

    2

commit e6efa87163649f328700d60f54f3a3cc587266aa
Author:     user <user@host>
AuthorDate: Wed Jan 1 01:01:01 2020 +0300
Commit:     user <user@host>
CommitDate: Sun Feb 2 02:02:02 2020 +0300

    1
```

меняем дату:

```
$ git filter-branch --commit-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="${GIT_AUTHOR_DATE}" git commit-tree "$@"'
Rewrite aef63a9e414abf06c92bae83c14269b1fa2b59a2 (2/2) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
$ git log --pretty=fuller
commit 4ad12c93f15065fcd6174807bd6b9fa7ccee02f6 (HEAD -> master)
Author:     user <user@host>
AuthorDate: Wed Jan 1 01:01:02 2020 +0300
Commit:     user <user@host>
CommitDate: Wed Jan 1 01:01:02 2020 +0300

    2

commit 5ef4883905240a32a4906af741dcca7e2daf8c05
Author:     user <user@host>
AuthorDate: Wed Jan 1 01:01:01 2020 +0300
Commit:     user <user@host>
CommitDate: Wed Jan 1 01:01:01 2020 +0300

    1
```

Comment: У rebase появился флаг root https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---root так что теперь можно и им

Comment: @AlexeyTen, `fatal: error: cannot combine interactive options (--interactive, --exec, --rebase-merges, --preserve-merges, --keep-empty, --root + --onto) with am options (.git/rebase-apply/applying)`